# How to use visual studio performance profiler ? after clicking start the application is running but not the profiler

Tags: c#, winforms, profiler

I'm using visual studio community 2022 V 17.8.5 .net framework 4.8

I did in the menu: Debug > Performance Profiler... then select checked the CPU Usage and then clicked the start button.

the application is running and i can play and do stuff with the application but i can't see anywhere the profiler window.

then after starting the profiler i started the application by clicking the start button with the green arrow and then i see this on screen but it's never ending even if i stop the application from running and i still don't see the profiler window.

[image: can't see the profiler window]

then i clicked Cancel and i see this message from the Diagnostics Hub:

'Images Scrolling' failed to launch

Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown.
Failed to enable provider {E13C0D23-CCBC-4E12-931B-D9CC2EEE27E4}: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
'Images Scrolling' failed to launch

Invalid operation detected by 'StandardClientTransportConnection.SendCustomMessageAsync'.

this is the profiler settings before starting it:

[image: profiler settings]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run the Visual Studio 2012 memory profiler? I'm getting the error DA0002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421201/how-do-i-run-the-visual-studio-2012-memory-profiler-im-getting-the-error-da000)

Comment: Update first to 17.9.2. Then select to run the executable, compiled in Release mode (from the button on the top-left side). Or start the Project in Debug mode. Start the profiling session just clicking the button you find in the Profiler window, after you have set these options (IMO, better not start a Project in Release mode, doesn't matter what the Profiler applet suggests).